# TypeError: that.getDestination is not a function

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use multer for the first time to upload images from node.js to mongodb and I was running a test code as shown below, to see if everything works, i followed the documentation and i can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

the full error is this :

TypeError: that.getDestination is not a function at DiskStorage._handleFile

```
  const router = require("express").Router();
const multer = require("multer");


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: {
    function(req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, "./uploads/");
    },
  },
  filename: {
    function(req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, new Date.now + file.originalname);
    },
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage:storage });

router.post("/images", upload.single("upload"), (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.file);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
multer({ storage:storage });
```

switch this for

```
multer({ storage });
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation as you.
from what I understand, you want to upload a file to place it in `./upload/` with as name `${Date}${Filename}`.

with the code i did i got what you wanted i hope this will help you

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

// this create a path like './uploads/'
const uploadsDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'uploads');

const storage = multer.diskStorage(
  {
    destination: uploadsDir,
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, `${Date.now()}${file.originalname}`);
    },
  },
);

const upload = multer({ storage });

router.post("/images", upload.single("upload"), (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.file);
});

module.exports = router;
```

if you want more info i found this in a github issue : https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/280

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination : (req,file,cb)=>{
        cb(null,"./Uploads/")
    },
    filename : (req,file,cb)=>{
        const fileExt = path.extname(file.originalname);
        // imp file.jpg
        const fileName = file.originalname
                            .replace(fileExt,"")
                            .toLowerCase()
                            .split(" ")
                            .join("-")+"-"+Date.now();
        cb(null, fileName + fileExt)
    }
  })

const multerObj = multer({
    storage : storage, // I did (dist : storage) instead of (storage : storage) do this hope you will get your result.
    limits : {fileSize : 100000000},
    fileFilter : (req,file,cb)=>{
        if(file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' ||
        file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" ||
        file.mimetype === 'immage/png' ||
        file.mimetype === 'application/pdf'){
            cb(null,true)
        }else(
            cb(new Error('Only jpg,jpeg,png file allowed.'))
        )
    }
});
```

Read the comment with code carefully and do this hope you will get your desire result.